# ERROR: Could not find local repository for 2.X.X

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have some error message on some my Jenkins builds

```
ERROR: Could not find local repository for 2.0.8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 17 09:16:50 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/281M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I search for the error message but Google cannot find any item for the following search: [maven "Could not find local repository for"](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22Could%20not%20find%20local%20repository%20for%22&oq=%22Could%20not%20find%20local%20repository%20for%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.2084032j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=maven%20%22Could%20not%20find%20local%20repository%20for%22&oq=maven%20%22Could%20not%20find%20local%20repository%20for%22&gs_l=serp.3...121611.122353.0.125400.6.6.0.0.0.0.71.342.6.6.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.psy-ab.a1drO-6ckUE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47883778,d.ZWU&fp=16bea6d2e6f81466&biw=1920&bih=965)

Without the quotes there is a lot of answer but I could not find a relevant one. The log appears only on 2.x builds, maven 3.x seems immune to this. I suspect that the source of the error is that I'm using several versions of maven on the same environment (the version are : 2.0.8, 2.2.1, 3.0.4).

There's no answer probably because nothing seems broken: the artifact is correctly installed in the local maven repository. 
But, in my humble opinion, a log with a ERROR level must be fixed.

Edit: the issue remains in Jenkins version 1.560.

Comment: It's a little different than your scenario, but I got this same error message when I had a jenkins job trying to use maven 2 to run a project built for maven 3.  Telling jenkins to use maven 3 instead fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check bug #18441. It was supposedly fixed in Jenkins 1.509.4 (2013/10/09) release.

http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog-stable

I say supposedly because we're still encountering it.

Comment: I confirm that the problem still exists in version 1.545.  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18441 the commit linked in the issue show it only solve the NPE, but nothing about the message itself. Thanks anyway.